# Stop logo from changing size when resizing window

Tags: html, css, image

```css
.top_card {
  background-color: steelblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem 0.1rem 1rem;
}
.top_card h1 {
  transform: translate(0%,-20%);
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.top_card h1 img { /*LOGO*/
  width: 20%;
  transform: translate(0%,26%);
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  font-weight: 900;
}
body {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", serif;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="top_card">
    <header>
      <h1>NEWS<img src="https://orf.at/mojo/1_4_1/storyserver//news/news/images/target_news-universal.svg" alt="Logo"></h1>
    </header>
  </section>
</body>
```

Whenever I size the screen down, the logo (img) sizes down as well. Any idea on how I can prevent this from happening?
I already tried adding "min-width: 20%" but that didn't seem to work.

My HTML code:

```
  <section class="top_card">
    <header>
      <h1>NEWS<img src="./img/LOGO.svg" alt="Logo"></h1>
    </header>
  </section>
```

My CSS code:

```
.top_card h1 {
    transform: translate(0%,-20%);
    font-size: 3.4rem;
  }
  .top_card h1 img { /*ORF Logo*/
    width: 20%;
    transform: translate(0%,26%);
  }
```

I already tried adding "min-width:20%" but that didn't seem to work.
Might the problem come from the logo being a .svg and not a .jpg/.png?

Comment: Please could  you include a runnable snippet that shows the problem? It's not clear how (whether) you are setting the size of a parent, but in any case width: 20% will be 20% of a parent and if that shrinks in size, so will the img.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `width` to a fixed size. Right now, it's set to `width: 20%` wich means 20% of the parent and the parent  has the size of 3.4rem which is root em. You can either set the `<h1>` to a fixed size or the `<img>` to a fixed size.

1.

```
.top_card h1 {
transform: translate(0%,-20%);
font-size: 40px;
}
```

2. 

```
.top_card h1 img {
  width: 100px;
  transform: translate(0%,26%);
}
```